# Comma to denote additional information that comes toward the end of a sentence and begins with a "-ing" word--is this a real comma rule?

Tags: punctuation, commas

Say I have the following sentence:

> The RES can be sprayed onto the burn wound, covering an area up to 80 times the size of the biopsy site.

I have a few questions.

1.) Most importantly, the comma. That comma between "wound" and "covering" **is** required, right? I strongly believe that it is, and I agree with how the sentence is written. However, after researching several resources on comma usage, I can't quite identify what comma rule this is. But this kind of sentence structure is used a lot. I could rewrite the sentence so that it's in a more basic (but more ugly) structure:

> The RES can be sprayed onto the burn wound so that the RES is covering an area up to 80 times the size of the biopsy site.

Now it's very explicit that the "covering" refers to what the "RES" is doing. (And if I'm not mistaken, a comma is no longer needed.) The effect of the comma in the original one takes out all those extra words, "so that the RES," and creates an elegant shortcut. Right? So what comma rule is this? One source I studied is this:
https://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/commas.asp.
The closest that I see is that it's rule 4a but with the sentence structure flipped around. Is that all there's to it?

2.) What is the term for that part of the sentence that comes after the comma? If I'm correct that it's basically just rule 4a in the link, then it's a dependent clause, right? I think that being able to identify the parts of the sentence helps to better conceptualize where commas are needed.

Comment: Yes, the _ing_ expression is a gerund-participial clause. The comma is required to mark it as an adjunct in clause structure. Omitting the comma may lead the reader to wrongly interpret the clause as modifying "wound", i.e a modifier in NP structure.

Comment: It does depend on whether the wound or the spray are "covering an area up to 80 times the size of the biopsy site".

Comment: @StuartF It's definitely the spray that is doing the covering. It would be more obvious if you could see the rest of the text from which I pulled this sentence.

Comment: @SvenYargs Sure, I removed it. I thought it was utterly incomprehensible that someone decided to close it for being "opinion-based"; it so obviously isn't. Maybe some mod on on this site wants to mess with me for some reason. And why would someone down-vote it?

Comment: A number of longtime participants at this site consider all questions about punctuation to be, at best, tangential to real English language and usage. It especially raises their hackles when someone asks whether a particular convention of punctuation is "grammatical." I think English usage encompasses issues related to punctuation norms. I acknowledge, however, that their view—which is premised on the idea that language is fundamentally concerned with the spoken word, not the written one, and that punctuation is a mere artifact of writing—isn't absurd, although it _may_ be opinion based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the term you are looking for is "participial phrase".

Here is a link from [Purdue Owl](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/mechanics/gerunds_participles_and_infinitives/participles.html#:%7E:text=If%20a%20participial%20phrase%20comes,modifies%20Ken%2C%20not%20residents.) which covers the use of participial phrases [as they classify what others class as ing-clauses; EA]:

**Punctuation**: When a participial phrase begins a sentence, a comma should be placed after the phrase.

- *Arriving at the store, I found that it was closed.*
- *Washing and polishing the car, Frank developed sore muscles.*

If the participle or participial phrase comes in the middle of a sentence, it should be set off with commas **only** if the information is not essential to the meaning of the sentence.

- *Sid, watching an old movie, drifted in and out of sleep.*
- *The church, destroyed by a fire, was never rebuilt.*

Note that if the participial phrase **is** essential to the meaning of the sentence [restrictive/defining], no commas should be used:

- *The student earning the highest grade point average will receive a special award.*
- *The guy wearing the chicken costume is my cousin.*

**If a participial phrase comes at the end of a sentence, a comma usually precedes the phrase if it modifies an earlier word in the sentence but not if the phrase directly follows the word it modifies.**

- *The local residents often saw Ken wandering through the streets*.

(The phrase modifies Ken, not residents.)

- *Tom nervously watched the woman, alarmed by her silence.*

(The phrase modifies Tom, not woman.)